# why isn't this loop stopping?

Tags: python, loops

```
while True:
    password=input("Enter a password. Make sure it:\nContains at least 1 capital letter\nContains at least 6 letters\n")
    time.sleep(0.35)
    if len(password)>5 and password.islower=="False":
        break
```

how do you make this stop. I want it to stop if it has one capital letter and is longer than 6 characters.

Comment: `password.islower=="False"` -> `not password.islower()`

Comment: `islower` is a method that returns a True/False value. You need to do `password.islower() is False`

Comment: or even `not password.islower()`

Comment: @Wondercricket : don't use the identity operator for equality test.

Answer (score 5):

Here :

```
password.islower=="False"
```

First, you're not calling the method - you need to add parens - so you compare a method with a string. It will never be true...

Then, once you fix this:

```
password.islower() == "False"
```

you end up comparing a boolean with a string. It will never be true either, you want to compare with the boolean `False` (no quotes):

```
password.islower() == False
```

As a last note, this is usually spelled:

```
not passsword.islower()
```

Comment: Not sure why this was DV'd, it is only answer that is correct and addresses all of OP's problems (at least the ones that are shown).

Comment: @Dan, addresses all of the problems except the one where he said 'longer than 6' and then tests for '> 5'.

Comment: @Duncan it doesn't say that. It says "at least 6", in which case `> 5` is sufficient.

Comment: @Dan the question says "long than 6", the code tests for and prompts with "at least 6".

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(password)>5 and not password.islower():
```

or

```
if len(password)>5 and password.islower() == False:
```

would work.

Comment: No it wouldn't. `islower` is a function.

Comment: Added the brackets to accomodate that islower is a function.

Comment: Parentheses != brackets :P (but code is correct; DV removed)

Comment: @Dan: Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Because `islower` is not a property but rather it is a function. Try this instead:

```
not password.islower()
```

In addition, as mentioned by @Dan, you compare the result of the `islower()` function (a boolean) with a **string** `"False"`. In Python a boolean result can be used directly as shown above without comparing it to a string `"False"` (this is wrong) or to a boolean `False` (which is weird and dangerous). `islower()==False` would be `True` if password *contains* upper case characters.

Comment: `"False" != False` (this still won't fix all of OP's problems)

Comment: @Dan Oh, I stopped "compiling" OP code at first error :)